# NSDictionary to xml string conversion in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml-serialization

How can I convert Request parameters of NSDictionary format to XML string. I have used the NSPropertyListSerialization method but it gives XML string in Plist format. I need a proper conversion method. Any libraries or custom serialization methods are available?

Please help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML) is a great library for writing XML in iOS. You'd have to parse the NSDictionary and build the XML tree yourself, but this way you will be free to structure the XML any way you want.